# Find all $a>0$ such that the following improper integral converges.

Tags: integration

The problem is integral:
$$
\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sec^a(x)dx
$$

I managed to think that if $a=1$, the integral diverges and by the comparison test, for all $a>1$ the integral also diverges.

However, I don't know what to do next. Since $a$ is a real number, I can't get its anti-derivative directly.

Comment: Look at [mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). But another thing you can do is click Edit (don't actually Edit it) and you will see how people write certain things using mathjax (and you can do this even with people's answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you can compare this integral to:

$$
\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(x)}{cos^a(x)}dx < \int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sec^a(x)dx
$$

This is true because $\sin(x) \leq 1$. Then we can do a $u$-substitution: $u = \cos(x)$ and $du = -\sin(x)dx$ and $u$ goes from $1$ to $0$:

$$
\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(x)}{cos^a(x)}dx = -\int\limits_1^0 u^{-a}du = -\frac{1}{1 - a}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left[x^{1 -a} - 1\right] \text{, for $a \neq 1$}
$$

So, just as you found, we see this definitely diverges for $a > 1$. Furthermore, since, when $a = 1$, you get the natural log, it also diverges for $a = 1$.

Clearly this integral *converges* when $0 < a < 1$, but that doesn't "help" us because our test integral is *less than* the original. *However*, it's *not* that difficult to multiple the $\sin(x)$ to make it larger than $1$. On the interval from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\sin(x)$ monotonically increases. Therefore we simply choose a particular value of $\sin(x)$ for $x > 0$ and multiply it by an amount large enough to make it larger than $1$. We then get:

$$
A\int\limits_{x_0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(x)}{cos^a(x)}dx \geq \int\limits_{x_0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sec^a(x)dx \text{, such that $A\sin(x_0) \geq 1$}
$$

Since $x_0 < \frac{\pi}{2}$, the first part of the integral surely converges. This shows that the "second" part converges, so the full integral also does.

**Edit:** To make this concrete (and this is *strictly* for $a > 0$...there's little doubt that the integral converges when $a < 0$), we choose an $x_0$ such that $0 < x_0 < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and an $A$ (along with $x_0$) such that $A\sin(x_0) \geq 1$. The original integral then becomes:

$$
\int\limits_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sec^a(x)dx = \int\limits_0^{x_0}\sec^a(x)dx + \int\limits_{x_0}^\frac{\pi}{2}\sec^a(x)dx
$$

We can bound the first integral by simply taking the smallest value (when at $x = 0$: $\sec^a(0) = 1$) and the largest value (when $x = x_0$: $\sec^a(x_0)$):

$$
\int\limits_0^{x_0} dx \leq \int\limits_0^{x_0}\sec^a(x)dx \leq \sec^a(x_0)\int\limits_0^{x_0}dx
$$

This means that the first integral is somewhere between $x_0$ and $x_0\sec^a(x_0)$. Finally the second integral can be bounded by:

$$
\sec^a(x_0)\int\limits_{x_0}^\frac{\pi}{2}dx
\leq \int\limits_{x_0}^\frac{\pi}{2}\sec^a(x) \leq A\int\limits_{x_0}^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^a(x)}dx
$$

**Left Part (Smaller):** $\sec^a(x_0)$ is the smallest value of $\sec(x)$ on the interval from $\left[x_0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, so then we just multiply by the length of the interval: $\frac{\pi}{2} - x_0$.

**Right Part (Larger):** This is because we have chosen $A$ and $x_0$ such that $A\sin(x_0) \geq 1$ and thus, for all $x$, $x_0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$, $\frac{A\sin(x)}{\cos^a(x)} > \frac{1}{\cos^a(x)}$.

The only thing left is to prove such an $A$ and $x_0$ exist. They do because $\sin(x)$ monotonically increases on the interval $\left[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, going from $0$ to $1$ (you can formally prove this by showing that the derivative of $\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)$, is greater than zero on the interval $\left(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$). If we choose any point, $0 < x_0 < \frac{\pi}{2}$, we can find the value of $\sin(x_0)$, then choose $A = \frac{1}{\sin(x_0)}$. Because $\sin(x)$ monotonically increases, if $A\sin(x_0) \geq 1$, then for all $x$ such that $x_0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$, $A\sin(x) > A\sin(x_0) \geq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that
$$\sec(x)=\frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)}.$$
Moreover recall that
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1,$$
thus near $\frac{\pi}{2}$ we have
$$\frac{1}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)}\sim\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}.$$
Then apply comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sec^a(x)dx = \int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\csc^a(x)dx = \int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sin^a(x)}dx$$
and note that $\sin x \stackrel{x \rightarrow 0}{\sim} x$.

Then you can use the [limit comparison test](https://services.math.duke.edu/~cbray/Stanford/2003-2004/Math%2042/limitcomp.pdf) for improper integrals.